# Making condition persistent after limit is reached

Tags: python, pandas

I m struggling to make conditions persistent after it is reached.

I have this sort of set up:

```
dft2 =  pd.DataFrame([[True,1],[True,0],[True,1],[True,0],[True,1],[True,0],[False,1],[True,1],[True,1],[True,1]],columns = ['a','b'])
dft2['c'] = np.where(dft2['a']==True,dft2['b'],0)
dft2["cumc"] = dft2['c'].cumsum()
limit = 3
```

Now if cumc reaches the limit (in reality this should be absolute limit). I would like to set 'cumc' to zero by putting the offset into 'c'. Then I would like to set all rows below to zero for both 'cumc' and 'c'.

This achieves the correct behaviour in the row where the limit is reached but not thereafter.

```
dft2["cumc"]=np.where(abs(dft2["c"].cumsum())==limit,0,dft2["c"].cumsum())
dft2['c']=np.where(abs(dft2["c"].cumsum())==limit,np.sign(dft2["c"].cumsum())*(abs(dft2["c"].cumsum())-1)*-1,dft2['c'])
```

The expected output would be:

Columns 'a' and 'b' unchanged and 'c' and 'cumc' as is but zeros from row 5 onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply find the index of the row where the cumsum is equal to the limit and then assign all the values after that to zero.

```
##look for the first index where the condition matches 
index = dft2[dft2['cumc']==limit].index[0]

## assign all values after that to zero
dft2['c'].values[index:] = 0
dft2['cumc'].values[index:] = 0
```

**Output:**

```
    a       b   c   cumc
0   True    1   1   1
1   True    0   0   1
2   True    1   1   2
3   True    0   0   2
4   True    1   0   0
5   True    0   0   0
6   False   1   0   0
7   True    1   0   0
8   True    1   0   0
9   True    1   0   0
```

Comment: thanks, very simple and nice solution. But it assumes that limit is actually part of the series. if it isnt it comes back with an error

Comment: what do you mean by limit is actually part of the series? Logically it should occur in it right?

Comment: no, it doesnt it is an upper bound that could be higher than all numbers in cumc

Comment: If that's it then why not put an if statement at the beginning to check if it is smaller and do the modifications.